# how to overwrite global css to div tag which contains different html tags with different style

Tags: html, css

I have one div tag as below:

```
<div id="summaryDiv">
    <span>
        <p style="font-size: 10px;color: red">this is test comment </p>
        <ul style="font-size: 8px;color: pink">>this is list of contents
            <li class="liSummary">lost1</li>
            <li class="liSummary">>list2</li>
        </ul>
    </span>
</div>
```

Now `summaryDiv` contains `innerhtml` summary which is not plain text but in form of formatted text.

And all formatted text may have different style applied inline or class.

What I need to create summary div css style globally which will overwrite to `innerhtml` formatted text.

So whole `innerhtml` will have same style at the end instead of individual inline style.

How to achieve this?

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: use !important to the style

Comment: Remove the style attributes from the added HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Check this out**](http://jsfiddle.net/Me5uj/)

```
#summaryDiv * {
    color: #ccc !important;
}
```

You'll need to use the `*` wildcard to select all children elements of `#summaryDiv` and then mark the overriding style as `!important`.

Comment: Nifty solution. I need to remember this one!